# Displaying pdf in Angular through <object> tag not working in Chrome if type is data-bind from variable

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am trying to display pdf in Chrome via `<object>` tag. 
It works if I manually write `type`:

```
<object [data]="getUrl(true)" type="application/pdf">
      Not working
</object>
```

But not if I read type from variable:

```
<object [data]="getUrl(true)" [type]="file.mimeType">
            Not working
</object>
```

Why? Is this some really strange bug, or I am doing something terrible wrong.

Here is [plunkr](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjsufp).

It works in Firefox (all 4 objects are displayed), but not in Chrome (`Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)`):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I don't understand the reason.

In my case I have decided to use the 'embed' element instead of the 'object' element in browsers based on the Blink engine.

```
<ng-template #blinkPlatformViewer>
  <embed [src]="getUrl(true)" [type]="file.mimeType"/>
</ng-template>

<object *ngIf="!isBlinkPlatform; else blinkPlatformViewer" [data]="getUrl(true)" [type]="file.mimeType">
  Not working
</object>
```

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class FileContentComponent {

constructor(private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private readonly platform: Platform)
  {
  }

  get isBlinkPlatform(): boolean {
    return this.platform.BLINK;
  }
}
```